# Разбить строку на блоки с учетом слов

Tags: python, алгоритм, строки

Мне надо разбить строку на равные блоки `chunks`, но с учетом слов в ней.

Например строка:

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
```

Должна быть разбита блоками по 5 символов как

```
['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet,', 'cons-', 'ecte-', 'tur', 'adip-', 'isci-', 'ng', 'elit,', 'sed', 'do', 'eius-', 'mod' ...]
```

В общем пробелы убираются, разве что если например два слова из 2х или меньше букв будет, например `"I am"` чтобы влезло, знаки препинания остаются, если не влезает в блок то ставится знак переноса - дефис, причем желательно конечно перенос ставить с учетом правил переноса конкретного языка (но можно и без этого).

Подскажите как такое реализовать? Просто блоками разбить не проблема, но вот с учетом слов по моему очень трудно будет... Можно на любом языке который я пойму, ну или например на питоне идеально будет.

Comment: А что Вы уже сделали? В чем проблема?

Comment: @IgorLavrynenko к сожалению я могу лишь просто разбить строку на блоки самым примитивным способом:

`def chunks(sequence, part_size):
    for i in range(0, len(sequence), part_size):
        yield sequence[i:i + part_size]
`

Могу также разбить строку по символам пунктуации на слова. Но как объединить эти действия я не знаю. :(

Answer (score 3):

Можно попробовать таким образом:

```
>>> a
'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.'
>>> aa = []
>>> for i in a.split():
...   if len(i) > 5:
...     aa.extend([i[j*4:j*4+4]+'-' for j in range(len(i)//4)])
...   else:
...     aa.append(i)
... 
>>> aa
['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet,', 'cons-', 'ecte-', 'adip-', 'isci-', 'elit,', 'sed', 'do', 'eius-', 'temp-', 'inci-', 'didu-', 'ut', 'labo-', 'et', 'dolo-', 'magna', 'aliq-']
```

Однако этот пример не учитывает окончание слова и не соединяет короткие слова разделенные пробелом, однако это не сложно реализовать, если у вас не получиться, я обновлю ответ немного позже.

Например для добавления окончаний можно выделить код разделения слова в отдельную функцию:

```
>>> def f(s):
...   a = len(s)%4
...   e = [s[j*4:j*4+4]+'-' for j in range(len(s)//4)]
...   if a:
...     e.append(s[-a:])
...   return e
... 
>>> f('qqqqwwwwee')
['qqqq-', 'wwww-', 'ee']
```

Answer (score 2):

Мой вариант

```
import math
line = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
size = 5
result = []

words = line.split(" ")
for word in words:
    if len(word) <= 5:
        result.append(word)
    else:
        parts = math.ceil(len(word)/(size-1))
        i, x = 0, 0
        while i < parts:
            if i == (parts-1):
                result.append(word[x:x+(size-1)])
            else:
                result.append(word[x:x+(size-1)] + '-')    
            i+=1
            x+=(size-1)
print(result)
```